# Samsung pc suite in ubuntu

Tags: android

is there a good android pc suit in ubuntu?!

I found Odin but it's not what I am looking for, then I thought about samsung kies but it's a windows *.exe I need "wine" to run it!

What to do?

Comment: What's the "Samsung pc suite" or "Android pc suite" supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

No, apart from Heimdall, there is no Samsung specific Android pc suite for GNU/Linux.

Depending on what you do need it for, there are a lot of alternatives though. I would use [kdeconnect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) on the Android device and your Ubuntu desktop for sharing notifications,clipboard and files (and a lot more), [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) for synchronizing photos in realtime, a caldav, carddav solution for sharing contacts and calendar (I don't use google services for such things). I think you can backup applications to google drive with android itself, though this is not a priority for me. For backing up sms and call logs, you can use sms backup+ on the android device and back them up to gmail or any IMAP server.

Other than that, only link I found to a similar app was [qtatb](https://qtadb.wordpress.com/download/), but it has not been updated since 2014 and I have never tried it.

Comment: "Apart from Odin" There is no Odin for Linux, but there is Heimdall.

Comment: @xangua You are right, I am not that good with nordic gods ;-). Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Airdroid](https://www.airdroid.com/en/download.html)

AirDroid is also one of the most advanced android PC suites for Android, Windows, and Mac. You can install the AirDroid desktop version on Mac, Windows and Linux and the android version on your mobile phone which will allow you to connect both the devices wirelessly. You can share all the photos which are present in your mobile phone, transfer the data and do all sorts of stuff with Airdroid.

Comment: I cant see an Airdroid desktop version for linux. Can you provide a link?

Comment: Who downvoted this? He must be a dimwit.

Comment: @Bruni You dont need to download anything on your PC. Install airdroid app in your android phone and go to web.airdroid.com and you can witness the magic.

Comment: interesting. Don't like the idea of this running on a third party server though, but it sure seems convenient. I did not downvote btw.